# How do I add a password checking middleware in node js express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, bcrypt

I am trying to make a middleware which displays a form which asks for a password to enter a route.

The problem is that I am in a get route and there is no way for me to pass the data in a get request because I do not want to pass the password in the url. So I tried to make a middleware which displays a form with hidden info like the id of what chat the customer wants to access which submits to another route (post). In the post route it checks if the password is correct and if it is goes back to the original route (get) and displays the chat.

Here's what I've done so far:

**The GET route:**

```
router.get('/chats/:id', middleware.isLoggedIn, middleware.isAllowed, catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    const foundChat = await Chat.findOne({
      _id: req.params.id
    })
    console.log('here', foundChat)
    res.render('chat/show', {
      chat: foundChat
    })
}))
```

**The POST route**

```
router.post('/chats/password', middleware.askForPassword)
```

**The middlewares**

```
middleware.isAllowed = async function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.cookies.allowed) {
    if (req.cookies.allowed.includes(req.params.id)) {
      req.body.password = null
      return next()
    }
  } else {
    res.redirect('/chats/password')
  }
}
middleware.askForPassword = async function (req, res, next) {
  try {
    const hashedDBPassword = await Chat.findById(req.params.id)
    const password = req.body.password
    const passwordHashed = hashedDBPassword.password
    const cookieName = encodeURIComponent(hashedDBPassword.name)
    const resultCompare = await bcrypt.compare(password, passwordHashed)
    let value
    if (req.cookies.allowed === undefined) {
      res.cookie('allowed', [], {
        maxAge: 30000,
        httpOnly: true
      })
    }
    if (resultCompare === true) {
      value = req.cookies.allowed
      value.push(passwordHashed)
      res.cookie('allowed', value, {
        maxAge: 30000,
        httpOnly: true
      })
      res.redirect('/chats/' + req.body.id)
    } else {
      global.nextMiddleware = true
      res.render('chat/password', {
        id: req.body.id
      })
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    res.redirect('/chats')
  }
}
```

**The form**

```
<% layout("layouts/boilerplate.ejs") %>
<form action="/chats/password" method="post">
<input type="password" name="password" id="password">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%= id %>">
<input type="submit" value="Go!">
</form>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate, why don't you use POST route then?

Comment: @PaulRumkin, i want to use RESTful routes

Comment: Let me make sure, do you use signed cookies?

Comment: @PaulRumkin no not really

Comment: Then your app would be vulnerable to externally set cookies. Bad actors will be able to set this cookie manually, e.g. from curl util and read any chat. 1. Use signed cookies instead. 2. Check actor id to match chat allowed users list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your code to be RESTful, then routes might look like this:

```
POST /auth
GET /auth
GET /auth/:sessionId
DELETE /auth/:sessionId
GET /chat/:chatId
```

Method `POST /auth`, should set authorization cookie and return `sessionId` to the client. Client can put `sessionId` into localStorage. Also there could be optional parameter redirect, which could redirect successful request to specified URL. But you should use it carefully, and not allow to redirect to external hosts.

Method `GET /auth` lists all live sessions opened by current user. It might be helpful when you need to close sessions on other devices.

Method `GET /auth/:sessionId` returns session by its ID. It can contain information about session, like last activity, device (browser or mobile), etc.

Method `DELETE /auth/:sessionId` receives `sessionId` from route, verify session ownership with authorization cookie, marks session closed in DB (if you store sessions in DB), and removes authorization cookie.

Method `GET /chat/:chatId` relies on HTTP only authorization cookie (work like it works now).

You can send POST request via XHR from the frontend, receive a successful response and then navigate to the chat.

Comment: you're probably receiving your bounty tomorrow because I have to check if it works

Comment: That's ok. I hope it will help you.